# Refining a Macro

Tags: ms-access, macros, formula, ms-access-2010

I am attempting to build a Macro which when a button is clicked will open a form but only show records which meet a certain criteria.

Currently i have

`[tblItem]![Status]=[Assigned]`

Which should only show records from `tblItem` where the value of `Status` is `Assigned`, at current when the button is clicked a pop up box appears titled `"Assigned"` and i can type in a value and only records with this value are then shown. But i would like this to happen without the popup appearing.

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved, was easy enough to render this question ridiculous.

`[tblItem]![Status]="Assigned"`

was what i needed.